# Okta OIDC Confirm Logout instead of id_token_hint

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, identityserver4, openid-connect, okta

I'm trying to setup RP-Initiated Logout flow from Idenity Server to Okta. Okta as External Provider in this case. I'm confuseing with **id_token_hint** that are id_token actually is. This means that we must remember id_token for logout purposes only.
So is any chnage to omit id_token_hint in Okta? I looked at https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html and rely on the text:

> the OP MUST ask the End-User this question if an id_token_hint was not provided or if the supplied ID Token does not belong to the current OP session with the RP and/or currently logged in End-User.

So does Okta have an options use this confirmaiton dialog instead of id_token?